# How to disable jquery swal confirm button initially

Tags: jquery, sweetalert

In my jquery project, I'm using swal with checkboxes like the below screenshot.

[image]

I want to enable/disable the swal confirm button based on checkboxes value and also initially disable swal confirm button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this with the below solution.

```
swal({
   ...,
   onOpen: function (element) {
      swal.disableConfirmButton();
      $(element).on('change', '[type="checkbox"]', function (e) {
        if ($(this).val()) {
           swal.enableConfirmButton();
        } else {
           swal.disableConfirmButton();
        }
      });
   }
});
```

Reference link: https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/issues/226#issuecomment-418703233